# Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'fetch'

Tags: backbone.js

I'm new to backbone and trying a simple fetch:

```
var segments = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url: function() {
            return '/campaign-mus/' +
            programmeCode + '/get-campaign-mu-json/get-segment-configuration-for-' +
            type + '/' + muId;
        }
    });

    segments.fetch().done(function(segmentsJson) {
        console.log(segmentsJson);
    });
```

which is giving me:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'fetch'
```

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: You must instantiate a model first as `new segments()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'segments' in your code is a "class name"(model definition), not an actual instance. you have to instantiate the model like so:

```
var seg = new segments();
```

btw, i'd suggest using capitalized singular words as "class"(model) names. eg.

```
var Segment = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

then

```
var segment = new Segment();
```